# Guest checkout redirect to account login page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

When I am not login and dont have account I still want to purchase item. But I am redirecting to create account page when I click on Checkout button.  At my admin side  option  of guest checkout is yes

Comment: Please make sure you have set it yes to  store level in admin panel.

Comment: @Yogesh what thing I have to keep yes ?

Comment: Yes you need to set it if you want to guest can place order. I have checked in 2.1.10 and its working fine.

Comment: @Yogesh I am asking which option ?

Comment: @Yogesh and what is store level ?

Comment: You mention that ** guest checkout is yes **  it place on this path Admin ->  Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Checkout options -> Allow Guest Checkout to Yes for your store.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68641/discussion-between-yogesh-and-learner).